# Ajax request with jQuery runs forever

Tags: jquery, ajax, undefined

I am working on a project and I would like to make use of Ajax as it makes everything more simple. But by this time it came up with a behavior I am trying to understand for days. At first, when I make an Ajax request using jquery, my response is always undefined. The server is at localhost and the page I am calling is totally correct. The response is in json format. 
The other problem came when I set dataType to json. If I set it, my ajax request runs forever and I never get an answer. Can someone please help?

```
        function setupAjax() {
        $.ajax({
               url:"http://localhost/dealer/cadastro",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function(res) {
                   alert(res.data)
                   }

               })
    }
```

Notice that res.data came from the server. When I directly access the page the result comes right, but when i am using this function i only get undefined.

**EDIT**

I found the solution. There's actually nothing wrong with my code and my requests.
For some reason, when I opened my page using my browser I accidentally opened the html file directly and not the http request, so instead of:

> http://localhost/app/teste.html

I was viewing:

> C:/wamp/www/app/teste.html

Now everything works just fine. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to use the console of Chrome, Safari or Firebug in order to debug it? Try some of the following thinks. First open your console in your favorite browser, reload your page and then make the Ajax call in order to see in Network tab if the Ajax call is correct. If is correct, modify your script into success: and instead of alert(res.data) enter console.dir(res) in oder to see what res contains in.

Comment: Verify that you're sending the response with content type header set to `application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a semicolon after the alert() and $.ajax() calls.

```
    function setupAjax() {
    $.ajax({
           url:"http://localhost/dealer/cadastro",
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(res) {
               alert(res.data);
               }

           });
}
```

Comment: Do you actually call this function somewhere else in your code? With `setupAjax();`?

Comment: Also, this could be an effect of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), if the client-side script is not also locally hosted. You would then have to use JSONP as a workaround. The jQuery API has examples of [using JSONP with Flickr](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Comment: This function is called from within another function. Everything is working fine but this! If I make the same ajax request outside the main function, it totally works.